# How to configure Let's Encrypt certificates for Service Fabric?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, lets-encrypt

Does Service Fabric support the Let's Encrypt certificates?

I want to use Let's Encrypt certificates and automate the process of renewing them.
Is there any tool available already which can help to add the Let's Encrypt certs to Service Fabric?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Avinash

Comment: there was a powershell module or something like that to work with Lets encrypt and iis. not sure if that helps

Comment: There's a feature request for this: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/293901-service-fabric/suggestions/33847168-let-s-encrypt-certificates-for-service-fabric

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I've found so far: https://www.troyhunt.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-loading-a-free-lets-encrypt-certificate-into-an-azure-website/

Sorry I'm not just adding the content here, as it's long, and the screenshots are pretty useful

If you find something that's one click, let me know - I wish Azure directly just supported as it's somewhat of a pain.

Comment: This doesn't help. Service Fabric is a Microservice Orchestrator like Kubernetes. The cluster deployment script should have a way to interact with Lets Encrypt. Currently, there is no guidance on how to use Let's Encrypt in ARM templates used to create the cluster.